# Setup a Google Analytics Goal / Funnel based on URLs that start with "/checkout/order-received/"

Tags: google, analytics

I am attempting to implement a goal for an ecommerce site in Google Analytics and I  am experiencing troubles.

So the goal / final destination for a purchase looks something like:

```
https://www.example.com/checkout/order-received/1234/?key=wc_order_XXXXXXXXX
```

So I know I need to implement something like this.

```
^/checkout/order-received/[^/]*
```

Though I am just not getting the syntax right. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Comment: It should be okay with /checkout/order-received/(.*)
If it's okay I write an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to select the destination URL as 
**Begins With**: `/checkout/order-received/`

This means that when that URL is reached, regardless of what follows (like `d=23w3e&b=12223`) it is considered as a goal.

I am supposing you are using WooCommerce. In this case I suggest you to set in the View Settings > Exclude URL Query Parameters all the get variables that you want to ignore in your data.

Example: key, utm_nooverride, tx, st, amt, cc, cm, item_number, sig

In this way in your Goal Overview you are going to have a report like this:

- `/checkout/order-received/3288/`
- `/checkout/order-received/3287/`
- `/checkout/order-received/3286/`
- `/checkout/order-received/3285/`